# FTP Server with advanced features

Tags: ftp

We supply zone-files to our customers. Some zone files are big about 300MB and some are quite small, maybe like 1MB. We had this issue that someone setup a script to continually download the file. Imagine downloading 300MB file a few hundred times a day. Since, we don't have packet-shaper to throttle the traffic, we need to upgrade ftp server and use add-on modules to limit the download somehow. We currently use proftpd server. Also note that there are different users for different domains - say, if you want to download zone file for .INFO domain, then you use a particular user. That user can't download any other zone's file. 
This is what we are looking for:

1. Have maximum of 400MB download per user per day. Or even have different download limit for different users per day.
2. Have one connection per user at any time.
3. Max # of connection (non-simultaneous) per user per day is 5. Anyone trying to exceed that gets banned for 24 hours.

Has anyone used FTP server with similar restrictions above? Does anyone have any ideas where I can start? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

-N

Comment: Is it possible to convince your customers to use `zsync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [mod_ratio](http://www.dynw.com/mod_ratio/) for Proftpd
- Proftpd has a [TransferRate](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TransferRate.html)
- [MaxClientsPerUser](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_MaxClientsPerUser.html) (you could check logs and then put the bans in place)

Comment: I'm guessing these mod_ratio has to be incorporated at compile time. Thanks

Comment: true, and I'm glad I could help..

Answer (score 4):

Not directly FTP-related, but I'd go and solve the cause (customers doing repeated downloads of the whole zone file) rather than slowing things around (with a possibly more complex setup). Have you considered:

1. giving out read only rsync access to zone files? it's standard, opensource, multiplatform (windows too), easily scriptable, good for frequent updates of big (zone?) files with little system and network load
2. kicking your customer's *ss. Politically correct translation: do you have an Acceptable Usage Policy? If not, go and put one in place. If yes, are your customers conforming or violating it? If the latter, just cut access until they fix their problem.

Zone files are big chunks of data with little parts changing, they scream for an incremental kind of transfer instead of full downloads every time.

Comment: +1 for mentioning rsync, which is something I'd look into myself when facing this problem. Capping your customers is not going to make them happy. Speeding things up with rsync will.

Comment: Instead of `rsync`, I would recommend `zsync`. Rsync could be more unacceptable, since it uses his own port, or ssh.

Comment: We have hundred of registrars as our customers. We have a contract with ICANN to provide download access to zone files to registrars - in many different countries. I don't think rsync will solve my problem. We do have an acceptable use policy but we want to be in such a position that no one who wants to violate that policy will be able to do so. Customers keep changing .. new ones coming on.. old ones going off etc etc. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @mkudlacek: If he's really restricted to using only HTTP, I can see where `zsync` fills a niche market; but otherwise `rsync` is more efficient and is basically the standard for this sort of task.
@Nikolas: Why don't you think rsync would solve the problem? They could continuously check, and if the file hasn't changed, rsync doesn't send it.

Comment: +1 for `rsync` over SSH -- more secure, you can use certificates without password and setup proper PKI to manage them.  Plus, you're dealing with a technical audience here -- if put to a vote, I'd say 99% of them would say yes to rsync (they don't want to waste bandwidth either).

Comment: Maybe I'm getting this wrong. So, I rsync the zone file to the download location. What happens if the zone file for registrar A is new, while registrar downloaded it 6 hours ago and the zone file he already has. I don't get how rsync will help me? Some registrars download the file daily.. some maybe once a month and there are some who have never downloaded them ever.

Comment: rsync will "copy" a file from system A to system B: if file doesn't exist on B, will transfer the whole thing, if it already exists on B will transfer just the changed parts, thus being much more bandwidth-friendly.
In your example registrar B will just update its copy of the file with your copy. I guess a lot of your bandwidth is from systems that already got the files, they just need to update them if they changed. You could probably cut your transfers by a factor of 10, using rsync instead of full file downloads. If you have a contract with ICANN you should know this kind of things...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/).  I believe it should have all the functionality that you are looking for.

Comment: it does except it doesnt have the "daily limit then ban" feature he wants.

Answer (score 1):

We have used CrushFTP running on Windows 2003. It works on other platforms as well and no clinet needed [CrushFTP Overview](http://www.crushftp.com/overview.html)

Many features for secure access with HTTPS and others. It can limit connections, set max file size and do other limits on access. Many other great features, low cost and great support. Have not tried V5 but last version has been great. Worth a look

Answer (score 1):

The [Bitvise WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd)  will probably do what you need via the wcfg config utility.